# How to programmatically control the CPU utilization by an C# winform application

Tags: c#, winforms, cpu

Is there any way we can cap the maximum allowed CPU utilization by a windows application developed in C# .NET apart from the thread mentioned at posting [controlling CPU utilization](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/261089/controlling-cpu-utilization)

Comment: Why do you feel the need to do that?

Comment: Indeed, I certainly wouldn't want any app on my machine attempting to do so...

Comment: Not an answer, but maybe you should set process/threads priority to lower levels instead.

Comment: I agree with macbirdie, set the priority lower.  It won't run more than anything else, but if nothing is running it will scale up to full CPU.

Comment: Is there something wrong with using all the CPU? If you are trying not to starve other processes on the machine, set the priority lower as others have said. If not, keeping an arbitrary percentage of CPU time unused is pointless.

Answer (score 0):

Not really, no. However, here is an answer on another site that suggests some third party tools that might help you achieve your goal https://superuser.com/a/214572.